# Resize frame to image size problem

Tags: qgis, raster, print-composer

I have an image the size of an A4 that I'm trying to place in a layout print in QGIS.

This is the image in an editing software. As you can see it has 210mm in width.
[image]

Here is the same image in QGIS layout, in an A4, with resize mode in "Resize frame to image size". As seen it doesn't cover the whole page.
[image]

What "image size" is it referring about seeing that obviously is not the image width and height? And how can I place the image with the exact same proportions as in the editing software case I wanted to place it in a page that was not an A4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image size for raster are always in pixel if you want to get a size in "real life" measure you need to set a resolution.

In a QGIS layout you have by default a resolution of 300 dpi for 300 dot per inches. You can change it here.
[image]

Your image software migth be set to open image with a 200 dpi resolution or to seek for dpi value in the picture metadata to give a size to your image. Just set the same value for QGIS layout.